# Non-isomorphic subrings of $\mathbb Q$ which are not fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

If we are looking for subrings of $\mathbb Q$ which are not fields, clearly the integers $\mathbb Z$ comes to mind as a first example. The integers are a subring, but not a field since not every non-zero element is invertible.

> I'm looking for another example of a subring of $\mathbb Q$ which is not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

I believe that any finite subring of a field is in fact a subfield, so, if I'm correct, we need a non-finite subring that is non-isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How about [dyadic rationals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational)?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ has no finite subring.

Comment: @ J.W. Tanner Dyadic rationals look like a reasonable candidate. I wonder if there is a more well-known example (or at least Dyadic rationals aren't well-known to me) And thanks @Berci, that's a good point. That makes my remark about finite subrings irrelevant.

Comment: Do rings have $1$? If $R$ is a subring of $S$, does $1_R = 1_S$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman A subring S of R needs to have the same multiplicative identity that the ring R has.

Comment: @MathieMcMatherson The dyadics are indeed an example! Moreover, they are in fact pretty well-known. And all examples will look similar to the dyadics in a certain way.

Comment: @MathieMcMatherson Good, I'm glad we agree :0) Not everyone does!

Comment: Instead of "find two non-isomorphic subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ which are not fields", a better exercise is: "prove that *any* two subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$ are non-isomorphic, and *no* proper subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field"!

Comment: @AlexKruckman I'm not sure that's better, though - if this question is not immediate it should definitely be worked on before proceeding to deeper questions.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, definitely. Maybe instead of a "better exercise", I should have said "a more interesting statement".

Comment: @AlexKruckman That's certainly true :).

Answer (score 4):

First, a couple quick comments.

You are right that any finite subring of a field is also a field. Luckily, this isn't an issue we need to worry about here - $\mathbb{Q}$ has no finite subrings.

*(Actually, this depends on the definition of "subring" here - sometimes the trivial subring is allowed, in which case $\mathbb{Q}$ has exactly one finite subring. But meh.)*

Moreover, note that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a "minimal" field in that it has no proper subfields *(it also embeds uniquely into every field of the same characteristic - this isn't relevant here, but it's neat)*. So really we can rephrase your question as:

> Does $\mathbb{Q}$ have any proper subrings, and if so what are they?

---

OK, so how do we find proper subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$? Well, they certainly have to contain $\mathbb{Z}$: they have to contain $1$, which gives all of $\mathbb{Z}$. So we're looking at "small" extensions of $\mathbb{Z}$ which get us partway, but not all the way, to $\mathbb{Q}$.

The way we get $\mathbb{Q}$ from $\mathbb{Z}$ is intuitively by adding "$1\over n$" for every $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (other than zero of course). This suggests a natural "partway" version:

> What about adding ${1\over n}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ for only **some** values of $n$?

Formalizing the intuition above is a good exercise - and in particular, you'll see that *primes* play a very convenient role. And a more intricate exercise is to turn the above into an **exact characterization** of the subrings of $\mathbb{Q}$.